# wordpress wp_insert_post adds page to the menu

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wpmu

Im adding some pages in my WordPress project programatically. To do so I am using the [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function. This works great, however. The pages will automatically be added to the menu. For some of them that is good but one of the added pages I don't want in there.

Is there a way to prevent this without removing it manually. I was thinking of removing it from the menu after creating the page, but I don't really know how and maybe there is a better/easier way to do so ?

My code for creating the page is:

```
    $inschrijfbevestiging = array(
        'post_title'   => 'Inschrijfbevestiging',
        'post_content' => '[inschrijfbevestiging]',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_type'    => 'page'
    );
    wp_insert_post($inschrijfbevestiging);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens automatically, you can remove it from the menu after making the page:

```
$objectWithPage = get_page_by_path('pageslug');
$menu_item_ids = wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items( $objectWithPage->ID, 'post_type' );

foreach ( (array) $menu_item_ids as $menu_item_id ) {
    wp_delete_post( $menu_item_id, true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when your menu not set before for one **theme_location**

You must set a menu to this **theme_location** so this never change automatically.

Comment: Thank you, I checked it but it seems to be set

Comment: check your theme , does it use "wp_nav_menu" in that area or use another method?

Comment: Yes, the wp_nav_menu function with theme_locations is set in the theme

Answer (score 0):

1.Login to the WordPress Dashboard.

2.From the 'Appearance' menu on the left-hand side of the Dashboard, select the 'Menus' option to bring up the Menu Editor.

3.Select Create a new menu at the top of the page

4.Enter a name for your new menu in the Menu Name box

5.Click the Create Menu button.

link: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Comment: I really do not want to do this in the gui, but tnx